# How to flatten a table based on following columns in Informatica?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, informatica, flatten

I am having source in the following format:

| Src | prty | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Source5 | 1 | A | B |  |  |  |
| Source3 | 3 |  |  | C | D |  |
| Source4 | 4 |  |  |  | D | E |
| Source5 | 5 |  |  |  |  | E |
| Source4 | 2 |  | B | C |  |  |

And I need the my target data like this based on `prty`:

| col1 | col1_src | col2 | col2_src | col3 | col3_src | col4 | col4_src | col5 | col5_src |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Source5 | B | Source5 | C | Source4 | D | Source3 | E | Source2 |

Basically, input data is all for one key but we don’t have that anywhere present.

However, if we see columns they’re all interrelated, using that relationship and based on the priority order we need to achieve target data.

Could anyone help me with this either in Informatica?

Comment: It's not clear how the example results relate to the example input data. Please edit the results to clearly match the example source data.

Comment: @MatBailie I made some changes and tried to explain as much as I could

Comment: revise you design but you are rerchig for unpivot

Comment: What happens if there is an A and a Z in Col1?

Comment: Why is Col2 matched with Source4? That has prty 2, but there's a B with prty 1 which is Source5...